# Приветствие в тг боте

Tags: python, telebot

Вечер добрый.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
 
def start(message):
    
hi_name = 'Hi, {message.from_user}'
    
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hi_name, parse_mode='html')
```

Есть такой кусок кода и в тг диалоге выводится вместо имени юзера `{message.from_user}`. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
hi_name = 'Hi, {message.from_user}'
```

делай

```
hi_name = f'Hi, {message.from_user.first_name}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Так-же дополню ответ выше. Вам нет смысла добавлять атрибут

```
 parse_mode='html'
```

Если вы не используете HTML разметку в сообщении и не планируете этого делать.